# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' Using BytesIO

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm getting a "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'". I was using StringIO and I got an error "TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes" I'm using Python 3.7.

```
    # Location of Alexa 1M
ALEXA_1M = 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/alexa-static/top-1m.csv.zip'

# Our ourput file containg all the training data
DATA_FILE = 'traindata.pkl'

def get_alexa(num, address=ALEXA_1M, filename='top-1m.csv'):
    """Grabs Alexa 1M"""

    url = urlopen(address)
zipfile = ZipFile(BytesIO(url.read()))
return [tldextract.extract(x.split(',')[1]).domain for x in \
        zipfile.read(filename).decode('utf-8').split()[:num]]
```

I also get the same error for this function as well. "return pickle.load(open(DATA_FILE))"

```
"""Grab all data for train/test and save

    force:If true overwrite, else skip if file
          already exists
    """
    if force or (not os.path.isfile(DATA_FILE)):
        domains, labels = gen_malicious(10000)

        # Get equal number of benign/malicious
        domains += get_alexa(len(domains))
        labels += ['benign']*len(domains)

        pickle.dump(zip(labels, domains), open(DATA_FILE, 'w').decode("utf-8"))

def get_data(force=False):
    """Returns data and labels"""
    gen_data(force)

    return pickle.load(open(DATA_FILE))
```

Comment: I assume `zipfile.read(filename)` returns **bytes**, but **str** is needed for `.split()`. `str(zipfile.read (filename))`

Comment: For debugging help, you need to provide a [mre] including complete code, input, expected output, and actual output, i.e. the full error message with traceback. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: "I'm getting a "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'"" Okay; and what exactly is your **question about** this error message? And *where* did it tell you the type problem occurred? What happened when you tried to ascertain the type of the input? Does the error message make sense to you in that context? Where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error basically says your string is **byte string**. To solve this, I think you can try to use `.decode('utf-8')`

```
url = urlopen(address)
zipfile = ZipFile(BytesIO(url.read()))
return [tldextract.extract(x.split(',')[1]).domain for x in \
        zipfile.read(filename).decode('utf-8').split()[:num]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Apparently it caused another error.

Comment: `return [tldextract.extract(x.split(',')[1]).domain for x in \`
    ^
`SyntaxError: 'return' outside function`

Comment: @swooz No, that's a totally different error. You probably messed up the indenting.

Comment: Your return statement is not inside the function. On the problem code you showed, the def and return is at the same level.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with another function.